# Use one form from Sonata-Admin in own Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

How to use Sonata admin - form in own bundle ? I want give for user allow to edit its own row in entity witch all relations. How to do it ? - prefer not give sonata admin link but put this one form to my bundle.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Tell us what you have tried. Or try posting some of your code.

Comment: i dont have idea how to do it - i have sonata admin - witch possible to edit my bundles witch sonata routes. Now i need share for user possible to edit only one row in entity. So want to have in in my route. Is possible to use for it sonata admin form ? something like this idea-  sonataAdmin()->loadForm('MySonataAdminForm')->loadEntity(entity)->renderForm ? - like i use symfony form (new form . put entity and have edit form)